# How to fix 'Supplier' object has no attribute 'id' when create a form?

Tags: python, django

I try to display the fields for the new supplier in form, but it has error 'Supplier' object has no attribute 'id'. What is the cause of this error?

Models.py

```
## Parent class
class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ....

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

## Child class
class Supplier(Person):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

forms.py:

```
class SupplierNewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
```

views.py:

```
def SupplierNew(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ## Save post data

    s = Supplier()
    supplier_form = SupplierNewForm(instance=s) `Error will occur here...`

    return render(request, "supplier_new.html", {
            'supplier_form' : supplier_form,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to send an instance for a new form. The problem is, django is expecting the `instance` to be an object which is already present in the database, but it fails to find one. Now, when you handle the code in `request.POST`, a new object would be created for you.

[Read more on this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

So, just change

```
s = Supplier()
supplier_form = SupplierNewForm(instance=s)
```

to

```
supplier_form = SupplierNewForm()
```

I would also reconsider the flow of the view method:

```
def SupplierNew(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ## Save post data

    else:
        supplier_form = SupplierNewForm()

    return render(request, "supplier_new.html", {
            'supplier_form' : supplier_form,
    })
```

By putting the `else`, if there are errors on form submission, you can re-render to the same template, and the form errors could be displayed to the end user.